# Titanium Mobile videoPlayer on Android not working

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, audiovideoplayback

I'm trying to play a .mp4 by clicking a button. I've tested this with different SDK's, heres the results:

1.7.5: Black screen when pressing button
1.8.0.1 & 1.8.1: Nothing happens

The event is registered as the alert 'Test' is working if it is uncommented. Here's my code below:

```
// Create main window
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

// Initialize the variable that will hold the playing video
var activeVideo;

// Create a play button
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Play Video',
});

// Add the button to the window
win.add(button);

// Listen for a 'click' on the button
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // alert('Test');
    // Create the media player
    activeVideo = Ti.Media.createVideoPlayer({
        url: 'video.mp4',
        autoplay: true
    });
});

// Open the window
win.open();
```

Comment: hey chris you are setting the media player to the var activeVariable, does that then need to be activated, .open(), or set to a viewable area or anything.  I don't have my Titanium stuff on this machine, but  looking at it seems there might be one more step? Have you tried other video formats? Is the path right?

Answer (score 1):

The video player was not added to the window. Try: `win.add(activeVideo);`